# Https connections from Android WebView

Tags: android, https, webview

I have a requirement to load some pages over https inside my app (in a Webview).
I know you can do

```
@Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        Log.d("SSL", "ERROR "+ error);
        handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
    }
```

But this eventually defeats the purpose of having https in the first place so are there any correct ways to do this, by adding client certificate to webview chain or even device chain so I can use SelfSigned certificates?

One more question , does doing handler.proceed();  disable encryption. i.e. if I send username using this connection will it be sent in plan form?

NOTE:If someone needs to make above workaround a little bit more "secure" you could check the domain in error object and only allow your domain test CN=my.domain.com

Answer (score 1):

In order to use any certificates that were not pre-installed on the device, maybe you can go your device  `Settings` -> **`Install from storage`** to have your new cert installed.

WebView used to provide the interface of `setCertificate()` but it's deprecated in API level 17, which probably means you cannot install cert from your app now.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried installing certificate on a device level (Galaxy S3) as you mentioned but it's not working. I even followed something like 5 tutorial just in case I missed something with certificate format or similar. Unfortunately it's still not working even in the browser and as it's mentioned in some tutorials webview doesn't read that global certificate storage. I did found that method along with it's "This doesn't do anything useful comment". But if I target earlier API would it still work on all devices?

Comment: If you were asking whether the API `setCertificate()` will work on all devices, the answer is no. And btw. "doing handler.proceed()" does not disable encryption; what it does is just tell the SSL layer that the app layer is fine with the unknown certificate (i.e. it  convinces the SSL layer the cert can be trusted).

Comment: Hm that not working on all devices sucks. Although since you mention that ignoring SSL errors doesn't disable the encryption I think in this case using a workaround I wrote in the note would be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to avoid HTTPS because it's hard to set up, checkout [nginx-local-ip](https://github.com/medic/nginx-local-ip) , basically it's a set of configurations that are launched with a single command (Docker Compose), and launches a Nginx reverse proxy that exposes in a Public URL your local webapp without the need of creating your own certificate, and without the need to setup the certificate in Android, nor DNS servers.

E.g. if your app runs on the port 8080, and your local IP is 192.168.0.3, it's accessible within your LAN at http://192.168.0.3:8080, but not with HTTPS, right? well, you only need to checkout nginx-local-ip, and in a shell session within the folder where the source code is stored:

```bash
$ APP_URL=http://192.168.0.3:8080 docker-compose up
```

Your app will be instantly accessible at https://192-168-0-3.my.local-ip.co (Note that the IP set in the `APP_URL` environment variable is passed as it is in your computer, but the URL to access the app separates each number from the IP address with `-`).

Do you need any DNS setup to access that URL? no, there is a public DNS provided for free by local-ip.co that takes care of that, so the domain `192-168-0-3.my.local-ip.co` points to the IP `192.168.0.3`, and `10-0-0-8.my.local-ip.co` points to `10.0.0.8` and so on. Checkout the README for more info.